# If I store an element in a javascript variable, will it check it again when I call the variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm storing the value of an element in a javascript variable, but the function needs to run asynchronously, so by the time the variable gets called again (after an AJAX reference) the value of that element may have changed, which I need to check.  Can I simply call the variable again, or will the variable just hold the value of that element when the variable was defined?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: To be honest, it's sitting in the middle of a relatively complex function and I didn't go through the steps of figuring it out myself.  Knowing the answer in advance saved me a lot of time troubleshooting.

Comment: That is when you dumb it down and make a simple test could have shown it. :)

Comment: ...yup.  You're absolutely right, and I feel silly.  I'm a bit scrambled today trying to get things done and I just wasn't using my brain, it obviously would have taken about 60 seconds to test this.  Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like two way binding to me, and the answer is no. A value will be copied, not included by reference. If you update the element with a new value, you will have to update the variable as well.

This is basically what Angular and Backbone try and handle for you - maintaining the ViewModel.